# О книге Н. Романовой "Идеальная грамотность"

Tags: литература, обучение

В Интернете рекламируют систему занятий петербургской панк-поэтессы и нейролингвиста Н. Романовой по обучению правописанию без правил. Я полистал электронный вариант её книги "Идеальная грамотность. Русский язык без правил и словарей". Кое-что заслуживает внимания, но в целом, как мне показалось, эту систему труднее освоить,чем традиционные правила правописания. Наверное, многие слышали об этом новаторе? Каково мнение коллег?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я эту книгу читала года три назад. Просто случайно попалась в "Молодой гвардии". Полистала, заинтересовалась и купила. Сразу скажу, что на практике что-то попробовать не удалось, т. к. на тот момент ушла в декретный отпуск.

С первых страниц понятна авторская позиция, этакий "свой парень", стремящийся быть "на короткой ноге" с читателем-подростком (основная предполагаемая аудитория).

Есть вещи спорные (моё мнение), например, с возможными ошибками в сложных словах, типа "милитаризм". Автор, если я правильно помню, предлагает писать не задумываясь. По её мнению, все ошибки в подобных заимствованных словах от того, что ученики пытаются найти в них какой-то подвох, сложность, не верят, что пишется так, как слышится, результат — ошибка.

Понравилось объяснение сложностей пунктуации. Предлагается запомнить определённый порядок действий, чтобы правильно поставить запятую и увидеть сложные места, например, где есть пауза между подлежащим и сказуемым, и школьник может поставить там запятую.

Итого — книга мне показалась  неоднозначной,  но интересной, заслуживающей внимания.

Answer (score 4):

Время такое, все разбираются в медицине, воспитании, обучении, назначении наук и религии и т. д. Давным-давно отработаны научные подходы к  обучению устной и письменной речи. И для этого нужен упорный труд! Изучать свой  язык надо всю жизнь. Давно это понято и сказано. Нужно постоянное самообразование!
Вот и нейролингвист Романова  предлагает свой метод обучения грамотности. Если следовать её мысли, то не надо ни грамматик, ни словарей, ни понимания сути языка и назначения речи, ни подготовки учителей, а надо вернуться к эпохе царапания на бересте.
А как же насчёт абстрактного мышления? Кажется, именно нейролингвист эти задачи должен хорошо представлять. Именно высокий уровень абстрактного — это то, что делает  нас мыслящими, разумными, грамотными. Вся грамматика и математика учат именно этому — оттачивают наше мышление. Другие науки уже выстраиваются на этой основе.
"Математика — царица наук, а язык - ключ ко всем знаниям" (Г. Р. Державин).
Серьёзная же проблема  в том, как учить, с чего начинать обучение и чем заканчивать. Именно учить, а не  п р о х о д и т ь материал.